# Send Message On WhatAspp Number Using Web Service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to send whatsapp message using MVC windows application, but i need a password, when i am using WART, so its getting error:-old_version
I am using GitHub "WART-master\WART-master\WART\WART-1.8.2.2.exe".
Whats-app get password error using WART?
Error:-Could not request code using either sms or voice.
SMS: {"status":"fail","reason":"old_version"} Sms is not comming
Voice: {"status":"fail","reason":"old_version"}Voice message is not coming 
My mobile country (India) code is +91`this is india no`